# Kubernetes Persistent Volume configuration

Tags: kubernetes, centos, yaml

My K8s cluster needs persistent storage

This is the pv-claim.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
    name: task-pv-claim
spec:
    storageClassName: manual
    accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
    resources:
        requests:
            storage: 30Mi
```

This is the pv-volume.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
    name: task-pv-volume 
    labels:
        type: local
spec:
    storageClassName: manual
    capacity:
        storage: 50Mi 
    accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce 
    hostPath:
        path: "kpi-mon/configurations"
```

and this is my deployment.yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}-deployment
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.name }}
    xappRelease: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.name }}
        xappRelease: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.name }}
          image: {{ .Values.repository -}}{{- .Values.image -}}:{{- .Values.tag }}
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - name: rmr
              containerPort: {{ .Values.rmrPort }}
              protocol: TCP
            - name: rtg
              containerPort: {{ .Values.rtgPort }}
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: app-cfg
              mountPath: {{ .Values.routingTablePath }}{{ .Values.routingTableFile }}
              subPath: {{ .Values.routingTableFile }}
            - name: app-cfg
              mountPath: {{ .Values.routingTablePath }}{{ .Values.vlevelFile }}
              subPath: {{ .Values.vlevelFile }}
            - name: task-pv-storage
              mountPath: "kpi-mon/configurations"
              
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: {{ .Values.name }}-configmap
      volumes:
        - name: app-cfg
          configMap:
            name: {{ .Values.name }}-configmap
            items:
              - key: {{ .Values.routingTableFile }}
                path: {{ .Values.routingTableFile }}
              - key: {{ .Values.vlevelFile }}
                path: {{ .Values.vlevelFile }}
        - name: task-pv-storage
          persistentVolumeClain:
            claimName: task-pv-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}-rmr-service
  labels:
    xappRelease: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  selector:
    app: {{ .Values.name }}
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: rmr
      protocol: TCP
      port: {{ .Values.rmrPort }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.rmrPort }}
    - name: rtg
      protocol: TCP
      port: {{ .Values.rtgPort }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.rtgPort }}
```

I'm trying to map local directory from the Pod file system
I choosed this documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/

When I try to load the deployment an error occurred and I cannot understand what the problem is.

Comment: When you need help to resolve an "error", it is usually helpful if you could describe **what** error message you get.

Comment: Also worth noting is that a `hostPath:` volume will mount the named directory on whichever random node the pod happens to be running on, so it's possible the place the pod is running isn't the same place that has the content.  If this is configuration of some sort, pushing it into a ConfigMap will make it more easily accessible.